# C2663 - unable to see const vs nonConst issue

Tags: c++

I keep receiving the C2663 error while compiling the following code. A search on SO reveals that C2663 points to a const/non-const mismatch, however I cant see this problem in my code.

The reduced code that still reproduces the error is

```
template <class QType> class QBound
{
    public:
    QType xMinVal, xMaxVal, xValStep, xCurrVal;
};

class QBounds
{
    friend class QBoundsHolder;
public:
    void add(const std::string & xP, const double xMin,        const double xMax,          const double xStep      );
    void add(const std::string & xP, const unsigned int xMin,  const unsigned int xMax,    const unsigned int xStep);
    void add(const std::string & xP, const int xMin,           const int xMax,             const int xStep         );

private:
    std::vector<QBound<double>>       xParametersDouble;
    std::vector<QBound<unsigned int>> xParametersUint;
    std::vector<QBound<int>>          xParametersInt;
};

class QMultiBounds
{
    friend class QBoundsHolder;                          
public:
    void add (const std::string & xI, const std::string & xP, const double xMin,        const double xMax,          const double xStep      );
    void add (const std::string & xI, const std::string & xP, const unsigned int xMin,  const unsigned int xMax,    const unsigned int xStep);
    void add (const std::string & xI, const std::string & xP, const int xMin,           const int xMax,             const int xStep         );

private:
    std::vector< std::pair< std::string, QBounds >> xData;
};

class  QBoundsHolder
{
public:
   template <class QType>   void  add ( const std::string & xP,    const QType xMin, const QType xMax, const QType xStep);

private:
    QMultiBounds   xParams;      
};

template <class QType> inline  void QBoundsHolder::add    ( const std::string & xP,    const QType xMin, const QType xMax, const QType xStep)
{
    this->xParams[0].second.add( xP, xMin, xMax, xStep );        
};
```

with the error being located on the last line (i.e. `this->xParams[0]...`).

Any help is much appreciated,
Daniel

P.S. A link to a minimum compilable solution that reproduces the problem is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zj3bcv7ckm3e3bc/Source.cpp?dl=0)

Comment: First of all, your methods and classes are a bit confusing probably because you have almost everything declared as `add....`. Also your signatures for `QBoundsHOlder::add` and the actual `add` that you are invoking from the last line `this->xParams[0].....` doesn't match. Also, if you are intending to `inline` your methods, be consistent and use inline both in definition and declaration. Please post what QType class is.

Comment: You use `xParams[0]` but neither see you overriding the access operator `[]` in `QMultiBounds` nor declaring `xParams` as array or vector. Do I miss sth.?

Comment: @hagubear: The `add()`s are deprecated versions of the actual names, the code box on SO does not expand to long lines. The second remark is true, but also a result of code deprecation for demonstrative purposes. Code edited.

Comment: @UniversE: I was going for a minimal code snippet that would show the error. In case it is needed, I can post a link to the whole code (1K lines). I did not show the operator[] to save space..

Comment: 1K code is a bit long. but still post it for us to solve the problem better.

Comment: @DanielBencik: a minimal example must still **demonstrate the problem**. i.e. except for the problem it must still compile. etc. so you must compile it before posting.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Edited. In my view the abbreviated code posted originally shows the problem better, probably a matter of preferences.

Comment: @DanielBencik: re your "in my view", it's not a matter of subjective opinion. the presented code does not demonstrate the problem. it (unfortunately, incorrectly) compiles fine with Visual C++ 12.0, and causes an error diagnostic about the invalid indexing with g++. there is a theoretical chance that there exists some compiler that emits a diagnostic numbered C2663, the same id as a Visual C++ diagnostic, and does this pretty randomly for the presented code, but it's on the same order of probability as getting a reindeer in your head when you stick it out the window.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Thanks, seeing the solution to my problem I understand why the original code snippet was useless. Lesson taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMultiParameterBounds::operator[]` returns `const std::pair<std::string, QParameterBounds>`, but `QParameterBounds::addParameter` is not `const`.

You probably need to add a non-const version of `QMultiParameterBounds::operator[]`.

Comment: Readers: this answer refers to code linked to in the question, not the presented code.